# Get List of Source in a video html5

Tags: javascript, html

hello i have a html5 video.

this is a example

```
<video width="320" id="video" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

i would a list of "source"

i'm write this code

```
var videotag = document.getElementsById('video'));

for (k = 0; k < videotag.childNodes.length; k++)  
{
  alert(videotag.childNodes[k]);
}
```

but not have a source.  it is correct childNodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is `getElementById` (singular), you have an extra `)` on line one of your JavaScript, you have a global `k` for no apparent reason, and `childNodes` will give you *all* the child nodes, not just the source elements so you should probably be using `querySelectorAll('source')` instead.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: @BeccaAlley — It's right there in the answer.

Comment: Hi  @Quentin,
var videotag = document.getElementsById('video'));

for (k = 0; k < videotag.childNodes.length; k++)  
{
  alert(videotag.childNodes[k]);
} 
Is not the answer so querySelectorAll('source')

Trying to figure out how to edit the top code.